# how to change font color and adding space on function in php

Tags: php, html

please don't laugh at me, but i don't know how to change colors and add spaces between words inside php funtion.
here's my code:

```
<td><font color="green">
<?php
   $response = json_decode($response, true); //because of true, it's in an array 
   echo $response['card']. $response['type']. $response['level']. $response['bank']. $response['country'];
?></font></td>
```

if you see that, i only know how to set the color to green only. what i want is that i can distinguish colors in each word and add spaces between words.
i tried to separate the php function one by one but that will cause an error. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline css styles, but it is not the best practice. Insert a string containing a space between your strings.

```php
<?php $response = ... ?>

<td>
  <span style="color: green;"><?php echo $reponse['card']; ?></span>
  <span style="color: blue;"><?php echo $reponse['type']; ?></span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can concatenate string with:

```
echo $response['card'].' '.$response['type'].' '.$response['level'].' '.$response['bank'].' '.$response['country'];
```

To change the color, you should CSS instead of `font` tag that is [deprecated](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp). Something like:

```
echo '<span style="color:green">'.$response['card'].'</span> '.
     '<span style="color:red">'.$response['type'].'</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

You create an array, which can be used further in the same page (read more about [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)).
So, after, you can use:

```
<td>
    <font color="green"><?php echo $response['card'];?></font>
    <font color="red"><?php echo $response['type'];?></font>
    ...
</td>
```

If you need to add spaces, you can do this with HTML or PHP.
With HTML just add a blank space " ". If you need more than one you can use special chars like  
With PHP, you can concatenate strings using `.`, like in

```
echo $response['card'].' '.$response['type'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To make spaces use `.' '.` in your case `$response['card'].' '.$response['type']`.

To change color use style `style="color:red;"` in your case `echo "<span style='color:red;'>$response['card']</span>".`